# How do I obtain the post content via a custom meta box inside the editor?

Tags: theme-development, metabox

I have a custom meta box which I would like to use to report on the markup of the current post or page (number of words, number of heading tags, etc).

How can I obtain the post content into memory in order to parse and report on its content inside the meta box?

Comment: Do you want the post as it was loaded into the editor (via the global `$post` variable), or do you want it client-side and update it there too? The [word counter under the editor](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/js/word-count.dev.js) does that by reading `$('#content').val()`.

Comment: Yes, I just need the post content as it was when loaded into the editor. I need to pass a keyword to a function that parses through the content to find the existence of the keyword in h1, h2 and h3 tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback for a meta box gets the current object (post, comment, link, ... depending on what you're editing) [passed as the first parameter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L2864). So in your meta box handler you can read this first argument and access it's `post_content` to get the content.

Comment: Thanks Jan. That was it. Any suggestions on how to parse the content and report on its markup? eg, given a keyword or keyword phrase that's assigned to the post, report on whether the keyword appears in a h1, h2, h3 tag?

Comment: @Scott: The only reliable way of parsing HTML is with the [DOM](http://php.net/dom). If it only is a limited number of tags, you could search for them and check whether their text content contains your keyword. If you want to find all keywords with their context I think you have to use XPath.